# Pods were terminated due to crashloopback

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, configmap

When getting the logs from rancher some of my `pods` in `Kubernetes` were terminated due to crashloopbackoff. How can I fix it ??. Attaching some screenshots for reference.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: can you please paste the logs of the pod

Comment: Instead of screenshot always use code block for better readability of a asked question.

Answer (score 2):

With available information on above question below is the assumption to your issue

> Exit code 150 and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

This looks to be a issue with compiled binary may be a version mismatched or correct .NET Core version not used.